# Storing in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, storage

I'm trying to get a string to read a file, that then stores all the digits in an array that can be recalled one by one in another loop. Name the array digitStorage please :D Here's my current bit of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 40000 ; i++) {             
    String digit;
    if ( i <=39998)
        digit = pictureFile.substring(i, i+1);
    else 
        digit = pictureFile.substring(39998,39999);
```

**My question :**

What to do, how could I do this, how would I get it to read each digit (single integers) 1 by 1 and then store them 1 by 1 in an array that could be later recalled, each number corresponds to a color that would be used to sketch a picture in a graphics window (there are 40,000 single digit integers in a file that i've already worked out how to read) ?

Cheers.

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: In what way does `pitureFile` consist of digits? Also, what is the purpose of the constants in your loop?

Comment: im guessing he wants to find out, how to store the digit string in an array outside his for loop so he can then reuse that array?

Comment: What is the format of your file?

Comment: @Danny Let me try again; what does your txt file look like? How are your digits stored in the `pictureString`? Are there spaces or commas between digits? We want to help you, but you haven't really given us anything to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you have already read the file and you want to store it in some kind of array. Below code will work.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 40000 ; i++) {             
    String digit;
    if ( i <=39998)
        list.add(pictureFile.substring(i, i+1));
    else 
        list.add(pictureFile.substring(39998,39999));
}
```

If you want List of Integer then us.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 40000 ; i++) {             
    String digit;
    if ( i <=39998)
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(pictureFile.substring(i, i+1)));
    else 
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(pictureFile.substring(39998,39999)));
}
```

You can iterate through `list` after this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I believe this should do it:

```
int [] digitStorage = new int[40000];
for (int i = 0; i <= 40000 ; i++) {             
if ( i <=39998)
    int[i] = Integer.parseInt(pictureFile.substring(i, i+1));
else 
    int[i] = Integer.parseInt(pictureFile.substring(39998,39999));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Please elaborate.

Comment: It is an ordinary array. Simply do, for instance, int digit = digitStorage[index];

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and question, the easiest solution I can think of is to use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) like

```
char[] chars = pictureFile.toCharArray();
int[] digitStorage = new int[chars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    digitStorage[i] = Character.digit(chars[i], 10);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digitStorage));
```